# How to enable the "Junk" in Microsoft Outlook 2016 (it is greyed out at the moment)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I was recently experimenting with Microsoft Power Automate and I run a flow which is sending multiple emails to my Outlook 2016 apllication.

I would like to redirect those messages to my spam folder but unfortunately the "Junk" button is greyed out in my Outlook 2016. I was trying to find a solution to it on Google and tried all the possible ways to fix it but unfortunately to no avail.

I attach the screen with the issue below:
[image]

If you have any ideas how to solve my problem please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test on Outlook 2016, I found that when the registry value "disableantispam" is configured for Outlook, the Junk E-mail option in Outlook is disabled. So, please check if this value is configured in your registry：

Registry Hive:  ***HKEY_CURRENT_USER***

Registry Path:  ***software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook***

Value Name:     ***disableantispam***

Value Type:     ***REG_DWORD***

Enabled Value:  ***1***

If so, please delete the "disableantispam" value or change the value to "0". And then restart Outlook, the Junk option will be enabled.

If you do not have this value in your registry, it is recommended that you try to create such a value and set it to "1" and delete it. And then restart Outlook to check if there're any differences.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. The solution you posted gives an answer to my question, many thanks.